# How can i set a menusettings checkable, true or false? and if it's true do something

Tags: python, pyqt5

I made a simple ui with pyqt5 autocompiler, everything works but i need to autoexecute a script, the autoexecution works but i will to implement it to an activate/disabled button (QAction set to checkable) located in the settings menu.
I want to set to him a state (T or F) and a boolean return if pressed

I'm on Windows

```py
with open("./startup.txt", "r")as f:
    f_contents= f.readline()
    startupis=bool(f_contents)
..some code....
self.actionRun_at_startup.triggered.connect(self.runatstartup)
self.actionRun_at_startup.setCheckable(startupis)

def runatstartup (self, checked):
   if(startupis==True):
        ....
   else:
      ....
   ....some code...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not very clear if you want the user to trigger the bool state or just keep that value.

In the first case, this will return the *new* value of the checkbox (if it was `False`, will return `True` once it's triggered, and viceversa):

```
self.actionRun_at_startup.setCheckable(True)
self.actionRun_at_startup.setChecked(startupis)
```

If you want to keep a variable, use `QAction.setData()`

```
    # ...
    self.actionRun_at_startup.setData(startupis)
    # ...

def runatstartup(self):
    if self.actionRun_at_startup.data() == True:
        # ...
```